# Can not do PITR with specific time in PotgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, pitr

I'm doing PITR with below settings and getting error as below.

```
archive_command = 'test ! -f /usr/wal_archive/%f && cp %p /usr/wal_archive/%f'
restore_command = 'cp /usr/wal_archive/%f "%p"'
recovery_target_time = '2020-12-09 15:20:00.0'
recovery_target_timeline = 'latest'
```

Error:

```
2020-12-09 17:43:43.029 IST [39613] LOG:  invalid checkpoint record
2020-12-09 17:43:43.029 IST [39613] FATAL:  could not locate required checkpoint record
2020-12-09 17:43:43.029 IST [39613] HINT:  If you are restoring from a backup, touch "/var/lib/postgresql/12/main/recovery.signal" and add required recovery options.   If you are not restoring from a backup, try removing the file "/var/lib/postgresql/12/main/backup_label".   Be careful: removing "/var/lib/postgresql/12/main/backup_label" will result in a corrupt cluster if restoring from a backup.
2020-12-09 17:43:43.030 IST [39612] LOG:  startup process (PID 39613) exited with exit code 1
2020-12-09 17:43:43.030 IST [39612] LOG:  aborting startup due to startup process failure
2020-12-09 17:43:43.031 IST [39612] LOG:  database system is shut down pg_ctl: could not start server Examine the log output.`
```

Any hint?

Comment: Looks like you didn't create `recovery.signale`.

Comment: I used steps from below article. I'm using PostgreSQL 12 so no need to create any file I think. Just need to configure recovery parameters in postgresql.conf file. https://severalnines.com/database-blog/point-time-postgresql-database-restoration

Comment: What will be the commands in recovery.signal?

Comment: It can be empty.

Comment: thanks. It's working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do people read blogs if all is spelled out in [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/continuous-archiving.html#BACKUP-PITR-RECOVERY)?

> 7. Set recovery configuration settings in `postgresql.conf` (see [Section 19.5.4](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-wal.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-WAL-ARCHIVE-RECOVERY)) and create a file `recovery.signal` in the cluster data directory. You might also want to temporarily modify `pg_hba.conf` to prevent ordinary users from connecting until you are sure the recovery was successful.

Comment: Hello Laurenz Albe,                                                                                      My PITR process works but I can not restore data at particular time. Do I need to give time in UTC time or I can give my local machine/server time ?

Comment: You can specify a time zone explicitly. If, you don't, the `timezone` setting will be used.

Comment: Thanks  Laurenz, After giving recovery_target_time in below format and it worked.                                                            
  "2020-12-11 14:34:28.833347+05:30"